# AttributeError: type object 'AdminSignUpForm' has no attribute 'as_view' why is this not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Creating a simple multiple users app. The `as_view` method is working with all the other views but not on this particular one. I have no clue why.

Here are my models

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Admin(models.Model):
    admin = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Admin'
    
         
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    quizzes = models.ManyToManyField(Quiz, through='TakenQuiz')
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, related_name='interested_students')

    def get_unanswered_questions(self, quiz):
        answered_questions = self.quiz_answers \
            .filter(answer__question__quiz=quiz) \
            .values_list('answer__question__pk', flat=True)
        questions = quiz.questions.exclude(pk__in=answered_questions).order_by('text')
        return questions

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Here are my forms.py

```
class StudentSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = StudentSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'student'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('students:quiz_list')
class AdminSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = AdminSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'admin'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('home')
```

Here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 480, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 696, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 689, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\mikha\django_school\django_school\urls.py", line 11, in <module>
    path('accounts/signup/admin/',  admin.AdminSignUpForm.as_view(), name='admin_signup'),
AttributeError: type object 'AdminSignUpForm' has no attribute 'as_view'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the *view*, not its form so the `AdminSignUpView`, not <s>`AdminSignUpForm`</s>:

```
path(
    'accounts/signup/admin/', forms.AdminSignUpView.as_view(), name='admin_signup'
),
```

Comment: How I didn't catch that is beyond me, need to get my eyes checked